# How to programmatically Login and Retrieve data from Google SMS channel Service using C#

Tags: c#, authentication

I want to programmatically login and access the data in Google SMS channels using C#. Eg. I want to retrieve data from http://labs.google.co.in/smschannels/channel/wordoftheday. How do I go about it. I looked at Google ClientLogin, but am unable to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

CodeGlobe has an article about how to programmatically login to [way2sms.com](http://way2sms.com) and send an SMS message. You may be able to use the same technique for the Google SMS channel. I haven't tried this, but  it may help you.

Here is the full article on sending SMS messages using C# with way2sms: http://codeglobe.blogspot.com/2010/02/way2sms-send-sms-c-code.html

Answer (score 0):

Well Its been a long time the question has been asked, but anyway google sms channel does not have an api so you wont be able to get the feeds programmatically but if you know the account user you can ask him for rss feeds and parse them using .NET or something.

There is no other way, but you know i hacked around google sms channels to send sms programmatically i just keep updating a .xml file and all the people subscribed to my channel get the sms.